# How to get Azure Products by product programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-management

I can get available regions for any Azure service using this page

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=storage

Is any API (REST for example or c#) to get this information programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`NO`**, There is no API option currently available to get those services. You can provide your own [`feedback or requirement`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/35606941-management-api-for-paas-saas-sevices) to get the support from the Azure Team.